# How can I automatically add default attributes to opentelemetry metrics?

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, open-telemetry

I am currently using interceptors in Java Spring Boot and `@before_request` hooks with baggages in Python/Flask to dynamically add attributes like the http endpoint and http method to all of my metrics.

I know, that I can add shared attributes to resources, but the attribute values here are fixed. I know that I can get some of this behavior by using Micrometer. But I want to know a "pure" OpenTelemetry way of achieving it. Is there an automatic way to do this instead of manually writing hooks and interceptors?

Answer (score 4):

For Java (with the javaagent), you can create an extension with a `ResourceProvider`. This allows you to dynamically define a resource.
Here's [an example](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/examples/extension/src/main/java/com/example/javaagent/DemoResourceProvider.java).

```
@AutoService(ResourceProvider.class)
public class DemoResourceProvider implements ResourceProvider {
  @Override
  public Resource createResource(ConfigProperties config) {
    Attributes attributes = Attributes.builder().put("custom.resource", "demo").build();
    return Resource.create(attributes);
  }
}
```

You can reference [this doc](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/examples/extension#build-and-add-extensions) for more info about extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Opentelemetry has some [env variables](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/configuration/sdk-environment-variables/), where you can define fixed attributes.

Check used Opentelemetry lib doc. It should be `OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES` variable, e.g.:

```
OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES="attribute1=value1,attribute2=value2"
```

Comment: good catch.  I forgot to mention that option in my solution. It has the benefit of being standard across all languages vs mine which is java specific.